# Replacing an input type text to an image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, replacewith

I have a list of input types I need to replace with their respective images.

```
<input type="text" id="user_fruitName_0_fruit_type" name="user[fruitName][0][fruit_type]" disabled="disabled" required="required" class="show_fruit form-control" value="MELON" />

<input type="text" id="user_fruitName_1_fruit_type" name="user[fruitName][1][fruit_type]" disabled="disabled" required="required" class="show_fruit form-control" value="STRAWBERRY" />

<input type="text" id="user_fruitName_2_fruit_type" name="user[fruitName][2][fruit_type]" disabled="disabled" required="required" class="show_fruit form-control" value="BLUEBERRY" />
```

The ID of each input are randomised so I can't use that as a unique ID. Tried this but it doesn't work because of the repeat of class.

```
    var str = $(this).attr('value')
    if (str = 'MELON'){
        $( ".show_fruit" ).replaceWith( "<img src='img/melon_logo.png'" )
    }
    else if (str = 'STRAWBERRY'){
        $( ".show_fruit" ).replaceWith( "<img src='img/strawberry_logo.png'" )
    }
    })
```

Any best way to do this? Help a noob here!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do, is hide the `INPUT` and have a DIV set with the background image shown there. If they click the image you can make the input to show again... Not totally sure what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: There won't be any action to it, I just want to replace the whole chunk of input type to an image. It works if I only have one, but I have multiple.